# Convergence in $L^1$ and uniform integrability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, uniform-integrability

> Suppose that $X_n\leq Y_n\leq Z_n$ where $X_n\to X$, $Y_n\to Y$, $Z_n\to Z$ in probability. If $E(X_n)\to E(X)$ and $E(Z_n)\to E(Z)$, show that $E(Y_n)\to E(Y)$.

I want to solve the task above.

I think the following theorem (which we have proven) is useful here:

Let $X_n\in L^1$ be a sequence of random variables and $X\in L^1$ then the following holds:

$\mathbb E(|X_n-X|)\rightarrow0 \iff  X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability and $(X_n)$ is uniformly integrable.

By assumption we have $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ in probability, so we just need to shot that $Y_n$ is uniformly integrable.

It is also clear, that $Y_n$ is uniformly integrable, if there is a $g\in L^1$, such that $|Y_n|<g$ for all $n$.

All I need to show now, ist that one of the integrable functions $|X|$ or $|Z|$ has the desired property. (But I don't know how to show this..)

Please read my ideas and help me according to my attempt. If my attempt is totally wrong, I will be very glad if someone can give me a solution, or better : some hints.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wasn't this asked very recently? By you?

Comment: No I faced this problem today, so this can not be true :)

Comment: So this was asked very recently--not by you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to show that $\left\{Y_n\right\}$ is uniformly integrable, given that $\left\{X_n\right\}$ and $\left\{Z_n\right\}$ are each uniformly integrable. To do this, there are two defining properties that need to be checked. In what follows, I assume that the random variables are all defined on the same probability space.

**Boundedness**: Firstly, we show that $\,\,\sup\limits_{n}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Y_n\right|\right]\right\}{}<{}\infty$.

Observe that, since $\,\,X_n(\omega)\leq Y_n(\omega)\leq Z_n(\omega)\,\,$ pointwise, then

$$
\left|Y_n\right|\leq\max\left\{\left|X_n\right|,\left|Z_n\right|\right\}{}={}\left|X_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|\geq\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}{}+{}\left|Z_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|<\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}.
$$

Consequently, for each $n$,

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Y_n\right|\right]&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|\geq\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}{}+{}\left|Z_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|<\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}\right]\newline
&&\newline
&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|\geq\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}\right]{}+{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|<\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}\right]\newline
&&\newline
&{}\leq{}&\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_n\right|\right]{}+{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z_n\right|\right]\newline
&&\newline
&{}\leq{}&\sup\limits_{n}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_n\right|\right]\right\}{}+{}\sup\limits_{n}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z_n\right|\right]\right\}{}<{}\infty\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

But, this is true for all $n$. Therefore, $\,\,\sup\limits_{n}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Y_n\right|\right]\right\}{}<{}\infty$.

**Arbitrarily Small Integrals**: Choose $\epsilon>0$. There exist $\delta_x>0$ and $\delta_z>0$ such that, for all $n$ and events $A$ with $P\left(A\right)<\delta_y:=\min\left\{\delta_x,\delta_z\right\}$, we have

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{A}\left|X_n\right|\right]{}<{}\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\,\,\,\,\mbox{ and }\,\,\,\,\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{A}\left|Z_n\right|\right]{}<{}\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\,.
$$

So, for any $n$, under these circumstances we have,

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{A}\left|Y_n\right|\right]&{}\leq{}&\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{A}{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|\geq\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}\right]{}+{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z_n\right|{\bf{1}}_{A}{\bf{1}}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right|<\left|Z_n\right|\right\}}\right]\newline
&&\newline
&{}\leq{}&\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{A}\left|X_n\right|\right]{}+{}\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{A}\left|Z_n\right|\right]\newline
&&\newline
&{}<{}&\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

**Edit**:@Kolmo points out, and I agree, that uniform integrability is not needed here. In fact, since $X_n, Y_n$ and $Z_n$ each converge in probability, they also converge in distribution. Consequently, the only thing we need to show is that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]<\infty.
$$
But, this must be the case, since $X$ and $Z$ satisfy 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]{}={}\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]{}\leq{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X\right|\right]<\infty
$$ 
and 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[Z_n\right]{}={}\mathbb{E}\left[Z\right]{}\leq{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z\right|\right]<\infty,
$$

so, using the bound on $\left|Y_n\right|$ given above,

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]{}={}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[Y_n\right]{}\leq{}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Y_n\right|\right]{}\leq{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X\right|\right]{}+{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z\right|\right]{}<{}\infty\,.
$$

Comment: Where did you get the assumption that $X_n$ and $Z_n$ are uniformly I tegrable?

Comment: @Kolmo, it follows since they converge in probability and mean.

Comment: Are you sure the convergence in probability and the convergence of the mean implies L1 convergence?

Comment: @Kolmo, :) thank you. How about now?

Comment: I still don't understand it. Why the only thing you need to show is that $E[Y]< \infty $? Also, i think, some absolute values are missing.

Comment: @Kolmo, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y_n]{}={}\mathbb{E}[Y]$ follows from convergence in distribution (which follows from convergence in probability). So, we only need to show that this limit "exists" i.e. is finite. And, to show this, we use the absolute integrability of $X, X_n$ and $Z, Z_n$ to bound $\mathbb{E}\left[|Y_n|\right]$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[|Y|\right]$. Note, this uses the fact that the $|Y_n|$ are dominated by the other random variables, as well as the convergence in distribution of all the random variables involved.

Comment: Are you saying: $Y_n, Y \in L1$ and $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$ then $E[Y_n]$ converges to $E[Y]$? This is false. If you are using other assumptions you should make that more clear for me to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Kolmo, Note: the $|Y_n|$s are bounded by the $|X_n|,|Z_n|$. If you have any more questions I will be happy to chat.

Comment: I still don't see it. Give me some time to think as I am at work now. If what you say is correct the theorem assumptions could be weakened assuming only convergence in distribution

Comment: I still don't get how you conclude that $E[Y_n] \to E[Y]$ from $E[Y]< \infty$ plus other assumptions (which exactly?). Also do you mean $E[|Y|]< \infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20048/discussion-between-ki3i-and-kolmo).

Comment: Also, in the last line you used the equality that needs to be proved